# Help resizing posted images

Tags: support, markdown, images

I often add pictures to my questions. Most of the time they come out the right size. Well, that used to be OK always, up until I started posting screenshots taken by my mobile. For example, this one:

[image]

This way, I'm sure you'll agree it is huge, decidedly too big, it takes up the whole body of the question, I mean. At present, the only way I have to resize it is the following code:

```
<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmRp.jpg" width="210" height="350" alt="">][1]
```

which I do not remember, and always have to recover from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/116958/82308). Is there a simpler, less HTML-hacky (and, I'd expect, more Markdown-based) way of resizing it?

PS The output of the above code is:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

Comment: Suggested reading on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow

Comment: And there's that duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can resize images uploaded to `i.stack.imgur` by appending a letter to the filename which represents the size.

s = *s*mall
m = *m*edium
l = *l*arge

So your image link is currently `https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmRp.jpg`, and to change the size you can do the following:

Small:
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmRps.jpg`

Medium:
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmRpm.jpg`

Large:
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmRpl.jpg`

Notice the "s", "m", and "l" after the `hKmRp` and before the `.jpg`.

So you can upload an image normally, and just add one of those three letters as required. Which one is best depends on the original size, and what is in the image (etc).

The full code in the post would be something like (for medium):

> `[![image][1]][1]`
>   `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmRpm.jpg`

NOTES:
Do not append any of those letters to keep it "original" size.
"Large" ("l") is slightly *smaller* than "original" (i.e. without any appended letters).

---

The above examples outputs the following:

### Small

[image: small]

---

### Medium

[image: medium]

---

### Large

[image: large]

---

### Original

[image: large]